# PROLOG , Operator expected when X in 1 .. 10

Tags: prolog, clpfd

whenever I try to set a domain for a variable , an operator expected error appears , here is my short piece of code , I'm using SWI-Prolog Version 7.6

```
    use_module(library(clpfd)).
    corn(L):-
    L=[M,W,C],
    M in 0..100,
    W in 0..100,
    C in 0..100,
    100 #= M+W+C,
    200 #= (M*6) + (W*4) + (C),
    W #= M*5,
    labeling([],L).
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. What line of your code does your error point to? It should give you a line number. Are you using SWI Prolog in this case? This isn't an error, but you can just say, `L = [M,W,C], L ins 0..100`. You don't need to set the range of variables individually since they're all the same. At the end, just use `label(L).` if you don't have any options for `labeling/2`. What does your subject "`X` in 1 .. 10" mean? I don't see that anywhere in the content of your question.

Comment: I'm using SWI Prolog and it gives me an error right after the M , the X in the subject I only used to represent my problem generally , also can you tell me what version are you using of SWI Prolog ?

Comment: You are missing `:-` before `use_module(library(clpfd)).`

Comment: Yes, you need in your file, `:- ` before the `use_module(...)`, unless you are typing `use_module(library(clpfd)).` at the Prolog prompt.

Comment: @damianodamiano and lurker :  It actually worked ,Thank you so much it really helped me a lot.